# C#-Indexed Properties?

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-4.0

I've been using Visual Basic for quite a while and have recently made the decision to begin learning C# as a step forward into learning more complex languages.

As a part of this jump I have decided to convert a few of my old VB projects by hand into C#. The issue I am having is with converting a library that had a class using properties with arguments/indexes.

The property would be something like this in VB:

```
Friend Property Aproperty(ByVal Index As Integer) As AClass
        Get
            Return Alist.Item(Index)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As KeyClass)
            Alist.Item(Index) = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

When I used the property it would be used like this:

```
Bclass.Aproperty(5) = new AClass
```

It is this sort of thing I want to achive in C# but cannot figure out for the life of me just how to do this as it seems C# can't do this sort of thing.

Comment: @Pharap why don't you just search for an online converter from VB.NET to C# I always use this one http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Comment: Should add a caution regarding this. If you create such a property in a VB.NET lib which you plan to access from C#, you'll fail. C3 compiler will suggest to use the only possible get_ and set_ accessors instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since C# doesn't support parameterized properties (which is what you are showing), you need to convert this code to two functions, a GetAProperty(index) and a SetAProperty(index).

We converted a 50,000+ LOC application from VB to C# and it required extensive modifications like this due to the dependence on parameterized properties. However, it is doable, it just requires a different way of thinking about properties like this.

Answer (score 4):

> Indexers allow instances of a class or struct to be indexed just like arrays. Indexers resemble properties except that their accessors take parameters.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx

Indexers are defined using the `this` keyword like this:

```
public T this[int i]
{
    get
    {
        // This indexer is very simple, and just returns or sets
        // the corresponding element from the internal array.
        return arr[i];
    }
    set
    {
        arr[i] = value;
    }
}
```

The .NET class library design guidelines recommend having only one indexer per class.

You can overload indexers based on the indexing parameter type

```
public int this[int i]
public string this[string s]
```

but not based on the return value

```
// NOT valid
public int this[int i]
public string this[int i]
```

Comment: T could be anything and doesn't have to be a generic type argument (it is one in the MSDN example).  You could have it return *string*, *MyClass*, etc.

Comment: You should return an array then. You want a method that will get the indexer as a parameter? You can do it with another class. I don't think you can do this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can specify a property only accessible with indexing, but you could just return an indexable value (like an array or `List`) and use `[]` on the result:

```
public List<Aclass> Aproperty
{
    get 
    {
         return this.theList;
    }
}

Aclass foo = this.Apropety[0];
```

Of course, anything with an indexer will work instead of `List`.

Or, you could do it the other way around: define an indexer (on the class itself) that returns an object that has a property `Aproperty`, used like so: `Aclass foo = this[0].Aproperty`.