# VB.Net stuck with setvalue method of system reflection

Tags: reflection, system, setvalue

A tons of advance thanks to everybody for taking time on this!

Am I doning this correctly? it says "Parameter count mismatch." for `SetValue` method

```
For i = 0 To (missingFieldName.Count) - 1

Dim propertyiInfo As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo =       
GetType(ImportFields).GetProperty(missingValuesTakenfromUser.missingFieldAcquired(i, 0))

  Dim fieldacquired As String = missingValuesTakenfromUser.missingFieldAcquired(i, 1)

  propertyiInfo.SetValue(fields, fieldacquired, New Object() {0})

Next i
```

fields is an instance of class ImportFields. tried a 100 different ways to work with this in last 2 days. desperately looking for a solution, please someone?

Answer (score 0):

For a non-indexed property, the third parameter should be null, not an empty array. Try this:

```
propertyiInfo.SetValue(fields, fieldacquired, null);
```

If you use .net 4.5, there's a new overload with only two parameters that you can use instead:

```
propertyiInfo.SetValue(fields, fieldacquired); // .net 4.5 only
```

Comment: thanks a lot for replying. the property that I am accessing is an array and i need to set the new value to its 1st element i.e. element 0. For i = 0 To (missingFieldName.Count) - 1

Dim propertyiInfo As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo =       
GetType(ImportFields).GetProperty("CustomerName")

  propertyiInfo.SetValue(fields, "New Value" , New Object() {0})

Next i

Comment: In this case shouldn't you rather _get_ the property value (i.e. the array instance), then set the array first element?

Comment: Not sure how to do this. what I want is assign a value to the first element of the array property. I have instance of my class ImportFields with the name fields. I have several properties in ImportFields class which are set from an ascii file. I run a system reflection to figure out which property was not set from the ascii file. I need to set that property to a value that I have taken from user in a textbox. I searched a lot and found system reflection has a method setvalue, I thought this should work for me. but you think I am wrong. please advise how can I achieve this. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got it after 4 days continuous struggle. here is how to do that

Many thanks to Jods for giving a tip above.

```
For i = 0 To (missingFieldName.Count) - 1

Dim propertyiInfo As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo =   
GetType(ImportFields).GetProperty(missingValuesTakenfromUser.missingFieldAcquired(i, 0))

 Dim fieldacquired As String = missingValuesTakenfromUser.missingFieldAcquired(i, 1)

 propertyiInfo.GetValue(fields, Nothing)(0) = fieldacquired

Next i
```

actually, MS is a bit confusing when they say indexed items. it meant to me they referring to array.

thanks a lot for everybody who struggled to solve this for me.

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. Glad you figured it out. The MSDN part that confused you refers to Indexed properties. Those are properties that take parameters, much like functions. They are totally unrelated to the return type of the property. In C# you can only use the default this[] indexed property, whereas VB.NET offers more flexibility and can define many named indexed properties. A few example déclarations can be found in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11711659/c-indexed-properties