# Asp.net C# error

Tags: c#

When I convert following vb.net code

```
Public ReadOnly Property MessageItem(ByVal ItemName As String) As String
    Get
        Return dsMessageContents.Tables("input").Rows(0).Item(ItemName)
    End Get
End Property
```

to c#

```
 public string MessageItem
{   
    get { return dsMessageContents.Tables["input"].Rows[0][ItemName]; }
}
```

I get an error that says

```
ItemName does not exist in current context.
```

Comment: `ItemName` does not exist in your C# code, you need to set it as a field in the scope of that property, or change it to a function.

Comment: Probably should be duplicate of [vb.Net - C# indexed properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11711659/c-indexed-properties)

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a property to replace a method. No need for the `get {}`.
Try adding the parameter "ItemName" to your method like this:

```
public string MessageItem(string ItemName)
{   
    return dsMessageContents.Tables["input"].Rows[0][ItemName];
}
```

Comment: I believe original VB.Net code is indexed property, not method.

Comment: perhaps, I missed the Property on his declaration, automatically assumed Function. Thanks Alexei